# tabbarview not keeping widgets persistent

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a profile page and in the middle, it has a tabbarview. the tabbarview has 3 tabs to display data of the user. The info is shown in the middle lower half of the screen. One has the bio tab, which I want to be edited when clicking a button.
A new screen appears to input the data and the data is returned so that the bio widget can be edited with the new text. However, when the screen returns to the profile page, the bio text does appear for like half of second, then it disappears. I tried the solutions found in stackoverflow and none of them have worked, expect for one which says to just declare a variable at the beginning of the file, so it will be accessed anywhere. and just make the variable equal to the input of the text, and have it displayed. It works but I would like to know why my error happens, so I can learn more about flutter. Thank you.

Profile code

```
class StudentProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  String id = "";

  StudentProfile(this.id);

  @override
  State<StudentProfile> createState() => _StudentProfileState();
}

class _StudentProfileState extends State<StudentProfile>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<StudentProfile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    studentProfilecreation profile =
        locator.get<localData>().collectionOfstudents[0];
    MediaQueryData queryData;

    queryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    //for tab bar in the middle to work.
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: Column(children: [
          //to position avatar pic and name, the two containers at top
          Stack(children: [
            Column(children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueGrey),
                child: SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 100,
                    child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/FINAL-FANTASY-VII-REMAKE_20200416212448-1024x576.jpg',
                        fit: BoxFit.fill)),
              ),
              Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 125,
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 25, 43)),
            ]),
            Positioned(
                top: queryData.size.width * 0.22,
                left: queryData.size.height * 0.02,
                child: SizedBox(
                    height: 125,
                    width: 125,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 0,
                        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(122, 0, 0, 0),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                            'assets/images/FINAL-FANTASY-VII-REMAKE_20200416212448-1024x576.jpg',
                          ),
                          radius: 60,
                        )))),
            Positioned(
                left: queryData.size.width * 0.40,
                top: queryData.size.height * 0.18,
                child: Text(profile.firstName + profile.lastName,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)))
          ]),

          Container(
              //to place the bar inside of the container
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                      top: BorderSide(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(22, 255, 255, 255), width: 1))),
              child: AppBar(
                  //the tab names
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  bottom: TabBar(
                    tabs: const [
                      Tab(text: "Major"),
                      Tab(text: "Id number"),
                      Tab(text: "Classes and\nnotes"),
                      //  Tab(text: "Bio")
                    ],
                    isScrollable: true,
                  ))), //),
          Expanded(
              //will take rest of the screen space, for each tab, the function of that tab will return
              //with singlechildscrollview.
              child: TabBarView(children: [
            MajorInfo(),
            myid(),
            CoursesandNotes(),
            // MajorInfo(),
          ])),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Bio method code

```
class MajorInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  MajorInfo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  String _major = "";

  @override
  State<MajorInfo> createState() => _Mymajorinfo();
}

class _Mymajorinfo extends State<MajorInfo>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<MajorInfo> {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Material(
                                child: TextField(
                                  onSubmitted: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      widget._major = value;
                                      //_temp = value;
                                    });
                                    ;
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  },
                                ),
                              )))
                },
            child: Text("Edit")),
        Text(widget._major)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

ignore the name of the class, it should be mybio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet when the "Edit" button is pressed, it opens a new route with a TextField wrapped in a Material widget.

When the user enters a new value in the TextField and submits it, you call `setState` to update `widget._major` with the new value. However, this doesn't work as expected because `_major` is an instance variable of the `MajorInfo` class.

The issue is that when you call `setState`, it only triggers a rebuild of the `_Mymajorinfo` widget, not the `MajorInfo` widget. As a result, the UI doesn't reflect the updated `_major` value because it's still referring to the old value stored in the MajorInfo widget's state and since `_major` variable is a property of `MajorInfo` widget,

What you can do is, declare the `_major` value on level of `build` function,
You can check this rebuilding by adding debugger, you will see Text widget rebuilding with Older value.

Comment: Awesome it fixed my problem thank you!